# ASP.NET WEBAPI Production Environment | "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: asp.net-web-api

`Local Environment { IIS 7.5 | Windows 7 | ASP.NET 4.0 | Integrated Pipeline}`

`Production Environment {IIS 8.0 | Windows 2012 Server | ASP.NET 4.x | Integrated Pipeline}`

WEBAPI functionality works in local environment e.g.

`http://<domain>/api/towncity?startsWith=Marston`

But on production, I received the following "obtuse" error message.

`{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The system cannot find the file specified","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":null}`

Any way to improve the error information?  Or do you know the solution?

Many Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Look at the EventLog on the server. It might contain more useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some investigation, the published RELEASE web.config, didn't update the WEB.CONFIG entities connection string.

It was therefore using the local settings for the entity connection string.

```
 <add name="YourDatabaseNameEntities"
     connectionString="
          metadata=res://*/Model.YourDatabaseName.csdl|res://*/Model.YourDatabaseName.ssdl|res://*/Model.YourDatabaseName.msl;
          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
          provider connection string=&quot;
              data source=<set datasource here>;
              initial catalog=<set catalog here>;
              persist security info=True;
              user id=<set user id here>;
              password=<set password here>;
              integrated security=False;
              MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
              App=EntityFramework&quot;
     "
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am currently looking at Scott Hanselman's piece on setting up different web.configs for DEBUG, RELEASE, and PRODUCTION.

[Tiny Happy Features](http://tinyurl.com/brl5tes)

Comment: Hey am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, solution is stated above.
Either configure Web Deploy in Visual Studio to use the correct Production Entity Connection String or create a new Build Configuration for Production and the corresponding Web.Production.Config transforms to use the correct Production Entity Connection String.  The Tiny Happy Features article explains custom build configurations and web.config transforms.

Comment: This actually worked for me...  I had specified an incorrect connection string name in my transformed web config.  Wow -- would never have thought of that on my own.

Comment: Updating the ConnectionString fixed it for me as well.